# CodeIgniter mostra erros estranhos

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação *CodeIgniter*, porém reinstalei o *WampServer*. No lugar onde existia um `form` agora mostra este seguinte código.

```
'id', 'value' => $id, 'size' => '6', 'readonly' => 'true')); ?> 
'login', 'value' => $login, 'size' => '15', 'readonly' => 'true')); ?> 
'email', 'value' => $email, 'size' => '30', 'readonly' => 'true')); ?> 
'senha', 'size' => '30')); ?> 
'novasenha', 'size' => '30')); ?> 
'novasenha2', 'size' => '30')); ?>
```

O que devo fazer para resolver ?

Comment: a sua tag inicial ta assim `<?php`, porque o `short_open_tag` deve ta `off`

Answer (score 1):

Coloque `<?php` no inicio, porque, o `short_open_tag` deve estar `off`. Não é boa prática (porque é melhor usar sem habilitação desse item, por causa dos servidores aonde tu vai disponibilizar seu site e a tag de abertura padrão do php é `<?php`), mas, se quiser edite no seu `php.ini` a configuração do `short_open_tag`:

*Ela deve ta assim:*

```
short_open_tag = off
```

*coloque assim:*

```
short_open_tag = on
```

Ou seja, ele não ta executando código `PHP`.

Comment: Olá, outra dúvida, antes o Cde igniter me mostrava os erros de programação de uma maneira melhor, agora mostra assim http://pt-br.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2qdr1ab&s=8#.U6JQ40Ck6So onde posso corrigir ?

Comment: @user11650 não entendi?

Comment: Antes ele mostrava os erros assim http://www.google.com.br/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FDP67M.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F13656999%2Ftrouble-in-codeigniter-taking-data-from-one-db-table-and-creating-a-entry-in-ano&h=800&w=1280&tbnid=gTzQnE5zDlkQiM%3A&zoom=1&docid=9T-6J6h8k7512M&ei=QFKiU4SUI7S_sQSDooGQDg&tbm=isch&ved=0CCQQMygJMAk&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=381&page=1&start=0&ndsp=14 , agora assim http://pt-br.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2qdr1ab&s=8#.U6JQ40Ck6So

Comment: Vixe não sei...

Comment: @user11650 a primeira questão foi solucionada? se tiver outra dúvida faça outra pergunta, se sim fecha essa questão!